# How can I dynamically assign control names at runtime in Access?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a number of datasheets that get used in subforms throughout my Access program. It is nice to be able to sometimes adjust the name slightly of the headers on these datasheets and then have this translate across my whole program. To do that I thought I would have a list of column names in a table (in MS SQL Server), with their aliases next to them in a second column. I use the column names as the control sources and the aliases as the names:

```
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String
Dim controlName As String

Set dbs = CurrentDb

For Each ctl In Me.Controls

    If ctl.Name <> "Student ID" And ctl.Name <> "NameField" And ctl.Name <> "Preferred Name" And ctl.Name <> "Course" And ctl.Name <> "Class" And ctl.Name <> "Current" _
    And ctl.Name <> "leftCourseFor" And ctl.Name <> "cancelled" And ctl.Name <> "termID" And TypeOf ctl Is TextBox Then
        strSQL = "Select aliasedName From dbo_assessmentNameAliases Where course = '" & courseString_glb & "'" _
        & " And assessmentColumnName = '" & ctl.ControlSource & "'"
        Set rs = dbs.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
        rs.MoveFirst
        controlName = rs!aliasedName
        ctl.Name = controlName
    End If

Next

rs.Close
dbs.Close

Set rs = Nothing
Set dbs = Nothing
```

However, I get the following error:

`Microsoft Access can't add, rename, or delete the control(s) you requested.`

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it. I found this code:
http://gainingaccess.net/Articles/RenameFormControls.aspx

I implemented it in Access 2013 and it worked perfectly. The trick is to instantiate the form without showing it, rename the controls, then deallocate the instance. Changes made to the form design will persist.

Answer (score 2):

You can only change Name in design view, but you can set the Caption:

```
controlName = rs!aliasedName
ctl.Properties("DatasheetCaption").Value = controlName
```